# Java: can't get .equals() to work

Tags: java, equals

I want to make a basic game where two random numbers are generated and the user has to enter the correct product.

What am I doing wrong? thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.awt.*;

public class Userinput {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String firstName;

        //Create scanner to obtain user input
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner( System.in );
        int a,  b, correctAnswer;
        a=(int) (Math.random()*10);
        b=(int) (Math.random()*10); 

        //obtain user input
        System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");
        firstName = scanner1.nextLine();

        //output information
        System.out.print("Hello " + firstName + " ");
        System.out.println("what is " + a +" times " + b);
        String answer1 = scanner1.nextLine();
        correctAnswer = a * b;
        if ((answer1).equals(correctAnswer))
            System.out.println("Correct!");
        else if (!(answer1).equals ("correctAnswer"));
            System.out.println("Incorrect!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think a `String` will ever be equal to an `Integer`?

Comment: @bhspencer I am not convinced your edit makes the code more readable.  Specially for new learners! (I think that's what white lines and spaces were invented for) yikes!

Comment: @ochi I removed unnecessary white space, added missing closing curly braces (so it would compile) and fixed the indentation such that it was consistent. Which of those things do you take issue with?

Comment: @bhspencer some of the vertical whitespace helped readability.

Comment: How so? Why do you need two blank lines between statements?

Comment: @bchspencer the white space I'd argue *is* necessary (for readability) - adding code to the edit is actually a no-no since you may be solving an issue (or introducing another one) - no issues with indentation (it's perfect, IMHO).  More to the point, a whole block of code makes it *less* readable than broken down/spaced statements

Comment: @bhspencer *some* vertical whitespace helped. Two blank lines is unnecessary, but one helps to delimit it into easier-to-read chunks.

Comment: @ochi I think the only indentation I fixed was the final println which was not correctly indented. Do you really think adding the closing curly braces is related to the problem the user was having?

Comment: @ochi I put a couple of new lines in to divide the code into the logical blocks defined by the OPs comments. Do you find that easier to read?

Comment: @bhspencer it reads much better, thanks; and no, adding a curly bracket at the end is not related to the issue (in this case) but (in general) missing syntaxic code sometimes *is* the issue so an edit (where you add the missing syntax) could remove the issue from the question.

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing a `String` (`answer1`) to an `Integer` (`correctAnswer`). That's comparing apples and oranges, they are never the same.

You need to either convert the `String` to an `int`:

```
Integer.parseInt(answer1)
```

which might fail if `answer1` can't be parsed as an integer; or convert the `int` to a `String`:

```
Integer.toString(correctAnswer)
```

and then compare them:

```
Integer.parseInt(answer1) == correctAnswer  // You can use == because int is primitive.
  or
answer1.equals(Integer.toString(correctAnswer))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where the problem is:

```
if ((answer1).equals(correctAnswer))
    System.out.println("Correct!");
else if (!(answer1).equals ("correctAnswer"));
    System.out.println("Incorrect!");
}
```

Do this instead:

```
Integer answer = Integer.parseInt( answer1 );
if (answer1.equals(correctAnswer)) {
    System.out.println("Correct!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Incorrect!");
}
```

The way that it is currently written, "Incorrect!" would always be printed, because of the semi-colon on the `else if`. Also, it was comparing `answer1` with the literal String "correctAnswer" because of the quotes. Since they're not even the same type (int and String), `equals(...)` returns false. I would also suggest using curly braces. It helps to alleviate some of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int answer1 = scanner1.nextInt();
int correctAnswer = a*b;
if (answer1==correctAnswer) {
  System.out.println("Correct!");
} else {
  System.out.println("Incorrect!");
}
```

There were a few issues with your code, mostly related to mixing up Strings and ints. [Here is a good explanation](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/difference-between-equals-method-and-equality-operator-java.html) of how to compare different data types. I would recommend that you use [Scanner.nextInt()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextint.htm) to save you having to cast Strings to integers.

I would also recommend that you do not omit the braces in your if statements. It makes your code easier to read and can avoid some confusion, especially when you are just starting out with Java.